# How to change background color of a div based on asp.net label value?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have an asp.net label (`lblFriday`) and a div next to it. `lblFriday` is showing the number data retrieved from database table. I want the div next to `lblFriday` to show a red triangle if the text of `lblFriday` is a negative number and green triangle if the text of `lblFriday` is a positive number.

Currently I've set the css class of the div manually with red color. Here is the code,

**HTML / ASPX :**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFriday" runat="server" CssClass="label_target"></asp:Label>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.arrow-down
{
    float:right;
    width: 0;
    margin-top:5px;
    height: 0;
    text-align:left;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
}
```

Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Where's the asp.net label?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by a negative or positive value? Are these numbers? Is there a submit button being fired to show whatever this negative or positive value is? I think more information is required to properly help you out.

Comment: I have some numbers in the database. My requirement is to show a green/red triangle based on % of increase/decrease in the numbers just like the stock market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that you need to do is adding `id` and `runat="server"` attribute to the div so it will be accessible from the code behind.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFriday" runat="server" CssClass="label_target"></asp:Label> 
<div id="divTriangle" runat="server"></div>
```

then you need to fix your css as follows, where `arrow-down` will show a red triangle facing down and `arrow-up` will show a green triangle facing up

```
.arrow-down
{
    float:right;
    width: 0;
    margin-top:5px;
    height: 0;
    text-align:left;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid red;
}

.arrow-up
{
    float:right;
    width: 0;
    margin-top:5px;
    height: 0;
    text-align:left;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid green;
}
```

then set the CSS class of `divTriangle` in your code behind based on the value of `lblFriday.Text`. Let's say the value is a decimal retrieved from database, here's what your code behind should look like:

```
decimal stockValue = ....; // get the value from database
lblFriday.Text = stockValue.ToString();
if (stockValue > 0)
{
    // set css class to arrow-up
    divTriangle.Attributes["class"] = "arrow-up";
}
else if (stockValue < 0)
{
    // set css class to arrow-down
    divTriangle.Attributes["class"] = "arrow-down";
}
else
{
    // no css class if stockValue is zero
    divTriangle.Attributes["class"] = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are binding the data to the label, you could do:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFriday" runat="sever" Text='<%# Eval("DATA") %>'
    OnPreRender="lblFriday_PreRender" CssClass="label_target" />
```

Then in the code behind:

```
protected void lblFriday_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lblFriday = sender as Label;
    decimal d;
    if(Decimal.TryParse(lblFriday.Text, out d))
    {
         lblFriday.CssClass += d < 0 ? " negative" : d > 0 ? " positive" : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

And finish with some CSS:

```
.label_target.negative::after
{
    content: '\25BC';
    color: Red;
}
.label_target.positive::after
{
    content: '\25B2';
    color: Green;
}
```